# leaflet with Mapbox

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Currently I am using Leaflet and Mapbox for creating map for my webapplication. It works well when I am connected with internet. My actual need is to get this map work offline. I have gone through many blogs/sites but I am not able to get this. How can I use Map box street map and leaflet offline?

Thanks,

Comment: You might consider _showing_ what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

Leaflet is the library displaying map data, it works online and offline assuming leaflet's javascript file is available locally/offline. But: Leaflet still needs the map data, in your case you want to use Mapbox Street. And this is only available online. So, the short answer would be "you cannot".

But there are other map data providers that can be used offline, often by running a map server locally. But such a map won't be nor possibly look like Mapbox Street's maps.

One way to go would be "mbtiles". It is a file format, a bit like a database, that contains usually pre-rendered map data for a certain region, and for certain zoom levels only. Leaflet should support mbtiles-files as layer-source.

Another way is to have your own map server run locally. This way you're also independent of any internet connection. The quickest/easiest way in my opinion is to use [OpenMapTiles.org](https://www.openmaptiles.org). They provide a good map server which can be locally run using Docker, and even provide worldwide map data based on OpenStreetMap data to go along. So if you run it locally, you're as offline as it can get with Maps.